# Should I delete my answer when it gets outdated due to version changes?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answer

I have an answer with 13 upvotes on this question [Can you disable VLC's font cache?](https://superuser.com/questions/189681/can-you-disable-vlcs-font-cache). It was never accepted as correct and now it seems VLC has changed so it is less useful than ever.

My first reaction was to delete it as I'm disinclined to edit it to match the current VLC, firstly because the new answer will be perceived as very good by users because it has 13 upvotes and secondly because I have stopped using VLC (because they keep changing stuff between frequent updates/bugfixes)

But before I do delete it I thought I'd get some input.

Comment: Can you update it?

Comment: Why not just edit it to say that it applies to an older version?

Comment: You could add another answer that is more up-to-date (and begin with a note along the lines of "_This newer answer applies to the current version of VLC, which is now v1.1.11_").

Comment: I guess the problem would be that it wouldn't get the same amount of votes, so updating and editing it would probably be better!

Comment: @slhck:  I think that's okay because the original question was about an earlier version of VLC.  Also, the votes for the original answer remain distinct, and newer voters can still vote for either answer (or both).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, as stated in the comments, the simple solution is to edit it with a few updates.

Note that if you want to put in a disclaimer, I always recommend putting that at the *bottom* of the post, not the top.

Comment: Any reason for the top vs. bottom?